# PayPal IPN empty array

Tags: paypal

I have development site on localhost, Sandbox set IPN return url to external IP, in form set return and notify url to localhost/...

After submission and succesfull payment script is going back to my notify url but $_POST array is empty

Please help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK I've managed to find an issue, now Paypal sents response behind the script so i have to log it into the file and see what happened or send it to the email.

Comment: Please mention that the issue you found

Answer (score 0):

You should add a new input field,//it will turn on paypal return method to "POST"

```
<input type="text" name="rm" value="2">
```

('rm','2'); //return method is POST
**rm = how you need the data submitted from PayPal to your IPN script (1=get, 2=post)**

Comment: I've set notify url to localhost

Comment: I have the same issue, i have set notify_url to localhost, but after successful payment, i am not redirected but freeze on paypal page. Also, to use ipn you need to enable it in merchant account. When i do so, i enter the localhost ip but i get invalid address error from paypal. does redirect work for you???

Comment: I would suggest you use a testing server, even one of those "Free PHP Hosts" for hosting, in case you don't have access to your own hosting account. Localhost/IP addresses don't work.