# IPN Variables not returned

Tags: php, paypal

Hi
I have a site in which paypal ipn is implemented with cart..
the Payment is working fine.
But after payment iam updating my database with the return value which is getting from POST from paypal
but now iam getting this POST array as null
Any one have the idea?
please help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is a similar question on SO already http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708646/paypal-ipn-empty-array Also for Paypal related stuff you might like to try their developer forums over at https://www.x.com/index.jspa

Comment: Just had a thought are you sure it is a POST back and not a GET request? Try using `var_dump()` on `$_GET` to see if there is anything coming through.

Comment: @Treffynnon when returning from `paypal`, everything is empty, `Querystring`, `POST` etc. paypal does not send any paramters when returning.

Answer (score 1):

`Paypal` now does not return parameters in the `POST`, they send those parameters via `IPNHanlder`.

IPNHandler is a background call which paypal makes to your site, and sends all the required `POST` parameters through IPNHandler. I had the same issue few weeks ago, but then I changed my logic and started using paramters from IPNHandler.e